# Hook with abortable fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, abortcontroller

note: I am aware of the useAbortableFetch hook. Trying to recreate a simple version of it.

I am trying to create a hook that returns a function that can make an abortable fetch request.

Idea being I want this hook to hold the state and update it when needed.
The update part is controlled by another competent on input change

What I am working on currently is

```js
function useApiData(baseUrl){
  const [state, setState] = use state({
    data: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false
  })
  const controller = useRef(new AbortController)
  const fetchData = searchTerm => {
     if(state.loading){
       controller.current.abort()
       controller.current = new AbortController;
     }
     const signal = controller.signal;
     setState(state => ({...state, loading: true})
     fetch(url + searchTerm, {signal})
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(data => {
          setState(state => ({...state, data}))
          return data
       })
       .catch(error => {
          setState(state => ({...state, error}))
       })
       .finally(() => setState({...state, loading: false}))
  }
  const fetchCallback = useCallback(debounce(fetchData, 500), [])
  return {...state, search: fetchCallback}
}
```

Usage

```js
  function App(){
    const dataState = useApiData(url);
    return ComponentWithInputElement {...dataState} />
  }

  function ComponentWithInputElement(props){
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    const onInput = ev => {
      setValue(ev.target.value)
      props.search(ev.tagert.value)
    }
    return (
      <>
        <input value={value} on input={onInput}>
        {props.data?.length && <render datacomp>}
      </>
    )

}
```

This seems to fail to even send the first request.
Any way to make this pattern work?

Doing this in a useEffect would be very simple but I won't have access to the input value to have it as a dep

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const signal = controller.signal
  fetch(url + value, {signal})

  return () => controller.abort()
},[value])
```

Comment: Can you show in your code where you actually call `search`?

Comment: Also if you could go into more detail about what you mean by `input value`. Is this just something case specific appended to the URL? I think we need to see the use case of where you are wanting to call this fetch, im assuming its in an event handler and thats what you mean by you dont have access to it.

Comment: Added an example usage snippet. The idea is that let's say this is a shopping cart that that autocomplete product names. I want the parent component be responsible for fetching the data and passing it down, but the input component should be able to update the input value on seelect or keyboard navigation

Comment: Gotcha, give me a sec to put an answer together

Comment: Having the input value passed down alongside data could solve this issue but the then I think the component is not that reusable

Comment: chenage to `controller.current.signal` should work

Answer (score 0):

Part of what you are trying to do does not feel "right". One of the things you are trying to do is have the state of the input value (like the form state) stored in the same hook. But those are not the same bits of state, as when the user types, it is (temporarily until it's saved back to the server) different to the state fetched from the server. If you reuse the same state item for both, in the process of typing in the field, you lose the state fetched from the server.

You may think, "but I don't need it any more" -- but that often turns out to be a false abstraction later when new requirements come about that require it (like you need to display some static info as well as an editable form). In that sense, in the long term it would likely be *less* reusable.

It's a classic case of modelling an abstraction around a single use case -- which is a common pitfall.

You could add a new state item to the core hook to manage this form state, but then you have made it so you can only ever have the form state at the same level as the fetched data -- which may work in some cases, but be "overscoping" in others.

This is basically how all state-fetch libs like react query work --  Your fetched data is separate to the form data. And the form data is just initialised from the former as its initial value. But the input is bound to that "copy".

What you want is possible if you just returned `setState` from an additional state item in the core hook   then passed down that `setState` to the child to be used as a change handler. You would then pass down the actual form string value from this new state  from the parent to the child and bind that to the `value` prop of the input.

However, I'd encourage against it, as it's an architectural flaw. You want to keep your local state, and just initialise it from the fetched state. What I suggested might be OK if you intend to use it only in this case, but your answer implies reuse. I guess I would need more info about how common this pattern is in your app.

As for abort -- you just need to return the controller from the hook so the consumer can access it (assuming you want to abort in the consumers?)